# Update if exist,otherwise insert

Tags: excel, vba, insert, updates

I got one situation and I will try to explain it.

I got excel file with two sheets (Sheet 1-Template, Sheet 2-DB). Template is used by manager who appoints yearly targets on monthly base. After state and approve the targets the data will be copy and pasted into DB. But sometimes manager can change targets after approve step.

In this point I need that if the data stated on Template exist on DB, Update, otherwise insert new lines. Actually I wrote code to insert lines but I couldn't write the proper code for check. Please help me on this issue.

```
Sub MonthlyTargetDB()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Target As Workbook:         Set Target = ThisWorkbook
Dim Tmpl As Worksheet:          Set Tmpl = Target.Worksheets("Template")
Dim DB As Worksheet:            Set DB = Target.Worksheets("DB")
Dim i As Integer:               i = DB.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Dim j As Integer:               j = DB.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Tmpl.Range("A5").Copy
DB.Range(DB.Range("A" & i), DB.Range("A" & i + 11)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

Tmpl.Range("B5").Copy
DB.Range(DB.Range("B" & j), DB.Range("B" & j + 11)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)


Tmpl.Range(Tmpl.Range("A8"), Tmpl.Range("B8").End(xlDown)).Copy
DB.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats)

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Use [WorksheetFunction.Match method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction.Match) to test if your target already exists. If it exists, then "update" is nothing more than delete (existing entry) and copy the new one (which you already solved).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thanks for your comment. I need adopt Match for multiple criteria. If you take a look on my code I copy the data from 3 different cells and as final result I need check all that criteria as the same time and if criteria meets, update the proper cell.